# Box2D - Going through and destroying bodies according to criteria

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am fairly new to Box2D, and I really need your help on that one! In my game, which is using Cocos2D for iPhone, I want my bodies to break things if they travel at a given velocity. Right now, all my bodies are dynamics and not sensors. When there's a collision, I call a function which determines if wether or not the crate should break. Here's the code :

```
- (void) contactWithPlayer:(Player *)_player{
    float recquiredVelocity = 8.5;
    b2Vec2 vel = _player.body->GetLinearVelocity();
    float playerVelocity = ABS(vel.x) + ABS(vel.y);

    NSLog(@"Player speed : %f", playerVelocity);

    if (playerVelocity >= recquiredVelocity) {
        [self breakCrate]; //Function that destroy the crate's body in the b2world
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but what I'd like to achieve is my player to go through the object if the crate breaks, at a reduced speed. Right now, my player only bounces on it! I've tried to re-use the `vel` variable and apply it to the player's body, but at that step the player already started moving in the other direction! I've tried to reduce the crate's density, but it just doesn't feel natural!

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** : The code I am using right now is a code borrowed on Ray Wenderlich's tutorials about colliding two objects using Box2D. So I have a class called `MyContactListener`that adds colliding objects in a vector, which is used later in my update loop in my game scene. Here's the update loop :

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)delta{
    [self checkCollision];
}

- (void) checkCollisions{
    //COLLISIONS
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
        MyContact contact = *pos;

        b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            GameObject *spriteA = (GameObject *)bodyA->GetUserData();
            GameObject *spriteB = (GameObject *)bodyB->GetUserData();

            if (spriteA.type == o_PLAYER && spriteB.type != o_PLAYER) {
                [spriteB contactWithPlayer:(Player*)spriteA];
            }else if (spriteB.type == o_PLAYER && spriteA.type != o_PLAYER){
                [spriteA contactWithPlayer:(Player*)spriteB];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the BeginContact callback of your contact listener, you can do contact->SetEnabled(false) to disable the normal collision response, and let the player go through the crate as if it was not there.

But that would not slow the player down at all. You would need to add a little impulse of your own to make the player slow a bit (some impulse in the opposite direction to movement should do it).

Comment: Ok so I should check for my speed inside the Contact Listener callback? Can't I check it in my update loop where I run through all my colliding bodies, and then set it disabled? Please check my updated question for the code I am using!

Comment: Yes, you would check the speed inside the BeginContact callback. I don't recommend the method on Ray's site, because it needlessly buffers all the contact information and then requires an inefficient second loop over every contact in the world. It's too late to disable contacts at that point, because it should be done inside the BeginContact callback as soon as the contact is detected. By the time your checkCollisions method runs, the collision response has already been applied.

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer that solution too, but my second loop seems necessery because I need to modify my player's body attributes if a collision occurs, and we can't do that in a callback (We get a world->IsLocked() assertion). So I have to check for the speed in my `BeginContact` method, and check any other collisions in my update loop. But now it's working, thank you a lot! :)

Comment: In the callback you can make a note of the fact that the player body needs modifying, and do it after the Step has finished.